# Dropping duplicates within groups only

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

I want to drop duplicates only in particular subsets from a data frame. Under each "spec" in the column "A" I want to drop duplicates, but I want to keep duplicates in the whole data frame (it is possible to have some rows under the first "spec" which are the same as rows under the second "spec", but under "spec" until the next "spec" I want to drop duplicates)

This is the data frame

df

```
  A          B            C
  spec       first        second
  test       text1        text2
  act        text12       text13
  act        text14       text15
  test       text32       text33
  act        text34       text35
  test       text85       text86
  act        text87       text88
  test       text1        text2
  act        text12       text13
  act        text14       text15
  test       text85       text86
  act        text87       text88
  spec       third        fourth
  test       text1        text2
  act        text12       text13
  act        text14       text15
  test       text85       text86
  act        text87       text88
  test       text1        text2
  act        text12       text13
  act        text14       text15
  test       text85       text86
  act        text87       text88
```

and this is what I want:

df

```
  A          B            C
  spec       first        second
  test       text1        text2
  act        text12       text13
  act        text14       text15
  test       text32       text33
  act        text34       text35
  test       text85       text86
  act        text87       text88
  spec       third        fourth
  test       text1        text2
  act        text12       text13
  act        text14       text15
  test       text85       text86
  act        text87       text88
```

I could split the data frame in "little" data frames and then in for loop drop duplicates for each of "little" data frames, and finally concatenate them, but I wonder if there is any other solution.

I tried also and succeeded:

```
dfList = df.index[df["A"] == "spec"].tolist()
dfList = np.asarray(dfList)
for dfL in dfList:
      idx = np.where(dfList == dfL)
      if idx[0][0]!=(len(dfList)-1):
            df.loc[dfList[idx[0][0]]:dfList[idx[0][0]+1]-1]
                     = df.loc[dfList[idx[0][0]]:dfList[idx[0][0]+1]-1].drop_duplicates()
      else:
            df.loc[dfList[idx[0][0]]:] = df.loc[dfList[idx[0][0]]:].drop_duplicates()
```

EDIT:
I have to add this to the end:

> df.dropna(how='all', inplace=True)

But I just wonder if there is any other solution.

Comment: Can you provide more information on your dataframe? You say you want to drop duplicates under `spec`, but in your expected result I still see loads of `act` and `test` in column A. How are these not duplicates of each other?

Comment: @jorijnsmit-I want to drop duplicates for the condition in the column "A" and that is from one value of "spec" to the next "spec" value...and when I said duplicates, I mean when the whole row is same, not the values from column "A".

Comment: It might help you to read up on how to build up a good dataframe. [Tidy Data](https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v059i10) is a really good starting point.

Comment: @jorijnsmit-Thank you, I will study it, but later, now I have to find some solutions quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `groupby` + `duplicated`:

```
df[~df.groupby(df.A.eq('spec').cumsum()).apply(lambda x: x.duplicated()).values]

       A       B       C
0   spec   first  second
1   test   text1   text2
2    act  text12  text13
3    act  text14  text15
4   test  text32  text33
5    act  text34  text35
6   test  text85  text86
7    act  text87  text88
13  spec   third  fourth
14  test   text1   text2
15   act  text12  text13
16   act  text14  text15
17  test  text85  text86
18   act  text87  text88
```

---

**Details**

We find all rows under a particular "spec" entry using `cumsum`. The group labels are:

```
df.A.eq('spec').cumsum()

0     1
1     1
2     1
3     1
4     1
5     1
6     1
7     1
8     1
9     1
10    1
11    1
12    1
13    2
14    2
15    2
16    2
17    2
18    2
19    2
20    2
21    2
22    2
23    2
Name: A, dtype: int64
```

The grouping is then done on this Series, and duplicates per-group are computed:

```
df.groupby(df.A.eq('spec').cumsum()).apply(lambda x: x.duplicated()).values

array([False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,  True,
        True,  True,  True,  True, False, False, False, False, False,
       False,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True])
```

From this, all that's left is to retain those rows corresponding to "False" (that is, *not* duplicated).

Comment: @coldspeed-Yes that's it. Thank you very much. You replaced a bunch of mine code with only one line...and for what `cumsum()` stands for?

Comment: @slobokv83 Cumulative sum. Helps keep track of how many "spec" we have seen so far. So all rows belonging under one spec are treated as a single group within the groupby.

Comment: @slobokv83 Added explanation, hope that helps.

Comment: @coldspeed-Yes, it helps. That is exactly what I need, and I didn't know that I can use `cumsum()`. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
df2 = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['A', 'B','C'])
```

Comment: @Rahul-I don't think so. I don't want to drop duplicates in the whole data frame, just in a subset.

Comment: Can you please explain your question in a more clear way because this `is possible to have some rows under the first "spec" which are the same as rows under the second "spec", but under "spec" until the next "spec" I want to drop duplicates)` is confusing

Comment: @Rahul-Sorry, my English is not the best. I want to drop duplicates for the condition in the column "A" and that is from one value of "spec" to the next "spec" value...and when I said duplicates, I mean when the whole row is same, not the values from column "A". Also, my code is working just fine, and you could look at it, but I just want to know if there is more pandas solution.

Comment: If I understood correctly, this  should work!! Updated my answer

Comment: @Rahul-Thank you for your effort, what I want is the answer from _coldspeed_.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution could be...
You can have a counter and create a new column from column A with the counter value, whenever you encounter spec in the column value you increase the counter value.

```
counter = 0
def counter_fun(val):
    if val == 'spec': counter+=1
    return counter

df['new_col'] = df.A.apply(counter_fun)
```

Then groupby on the new_col, and drop duplicates.

Comment: @Pradeep-Thank you for answering, but I think that is not the solution.